# Okay to set flag-like custom properties on arrays and DOM elements?

Tags: javascript

The basic reason for asking is that I want to avoid having to repeat multiple type checks when performing similar operations with the same input.  Ie.,

```
const isElement = (el) => {
    if (el["isElement"]) { 
        return el["isElement"] 
    } else { 
        return (el["isElement"] = ...some verbose typecheck...)
    }
}

const addClass = (el, cls) => isElement(el) && el.classList.add("cls")

const style = (el,prop,s) => isElement(el) && (el.style[prop] = s)

const handleClick = (el) => {
    addClass(el, "whatevs")
    style(el, "what", "evspx")
    // running this would unnecessarily check twice if el is an element  
}
```

So would it be permissible and/or possible to set custom flags on the input to be able to save time processing?

It very well could be a minute improvement, but it would put my mind at ease in times when I worry about the waste of running multiple array/object/elements type checks duplicative numbers of times on the same input in a single pipeline.

Comment: I do not recommend doing this on DOM elements. There's no guarantee that all browsers will allow this. On some browsers, the properties might not "stick", on others, this could possibly even throw errors, especially in `strict mode`. Please don't do this in production code, just stick with the "verbose typecheck".

Comment: On a side note, this is as simple as doing `if (el instanceof HTMLElement)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is it OK, it's a prime feature of the language. Having said this, let's be clear that it is generally **not** a good idea to modify the underlying types, but customizing your own inherited version is quite acceptable.

So, this would be bad:

```
Array.prototype.myCustomProperty = ...
```

But, this would be good:

```
// This creates a new array and sets it with its own instance of an Array
// as its prototype. 
var myCustomArray = [];

// Modifying this prototype doesn't modify the native `Array.prototype`
myCustomArray.prototype.myCustomProperty = ...
```

TEST:

```js
    var myCustomArray = [];

    // Your array's prototype is not the same instance that the native Array uses
    console.log(myCustomArray.prototype === Array.prototype);
```

Comment: Two nitpicks: change `myCustomArray` to `MyCustomArray`, and change `var myCustomArray = [];` to `var MyCustomArray = Object.create(Array.prototype);` or better yet, `class MyCustomArray extends Array { ... }`

Comment: Understood. And I also know that modifying properties on prototypes hinders compilers from parsing the code.  But would this fall in that category? I'm not trying to add methods to the prototype, but rather just simple quick access lookup properties.

Errr @Patrick Roberts... So wait, am I (or do I need to, which I wont) create my own custom array object in order for this to work?  In simple dev tools tests, it seemed to work fine.

Comment: @JonathanLatt Actually, JavaScript objects technically don't have methods at all - - only properties. It's just that some properties hold raw data and others hold functions, so there really isn't a distinction between adding a "method" to a prototype vs. adding a "property" to a prototype.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think his point was that he's not modifying the prototype, but rather individual instances on the fly. I don't believe that doing either is a good practice though.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I understand and don't necessarily disagree, but `Object.create()` and `class` are really syntactic sugar that abstracts what I'm showing. I would say that modifying a singe type on the fly would be more dangerous than setting up a new prototype to work with. In the end, doing it on a particular instance here and there isn't scaleable and will most likely lead to bugs.

Comment: @ScottMarcus `Object.create()` is **not** syntactic sugar. Using an array literal invokes the parent class's constructor, whereas using `Object.create()` on the prototype does not invoke the parent class's constructor.

Comment: What foreseeable bugs would it lead to though?

Comment: I would say that it is, but I would again advise you to create a new inherited type and modify the prototype of that type than to do it as "on the fly" own properties here and there.

Comment: @JonathanLatt Having multiple instances with conflicting properties.

Comment: Alright, well thanks @ScottMarcus and PatrickRoberts for the input and conversation.  Much appreciated.